# Number of Atoms in a Probability Space

Tags: probability-theory

How could one show that the number of atoms in an uncountable probability space is at most countable?

Answer (score 5):

Let $B$ be a set of positive real numbers. Then $B=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ where $B_n = \{ x \in B : x > 1/n \}$. Now

$$\sum_{x \in B} x \geq \sum_{x \in B_n} x \geq |B_n|/n.$$

So either $B_n$ is finite or else $\sum_{x \in B}$ is infinite. So if we assume that $\sum_{x \in B}$ is finite, then $B$ must be countable, because it is a countable union of finite sets.

I have proven that an uncountable sum of positive numbers is infinite. You can use this to derive your result.

Comment: The question asks about an arbitrary uncountable probability space. Also, where is the definition of an atom used here? Atom reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)

Comment: @coffeemath I am adding up the probabilities of all the atoms and concluding that I get $\infty $.

Comment: In general these $B_n$ don't need to be atoms, they might have proper subsets having positive probability.

Comment: @coffeemath To apply this result in your context, define $B$ so that each element of $B$ is the measure of one of the atoms. Then the measure of the entire space is at least the sum of all the elements of $B$.

Comment: Ian-- Yes I see the measure of the space is at least the sum of measures of the atoms. But there isn't a probability formula for directly getting the probability of an uncountable disjoint union. There is a workaround however which shows what you claim here. +1 on answer...

Comment: @coffeemath I think you actually always have that the measure of *any* disjoint union is at least the sum of the measures of the components. Sometimes this is vacuous (for instance, when singletons have measure zero), but in this case I think it gets you the result.